# Get input-field value send to another input-field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to copy value from an input field and send it to another `onkeyup` but it only extracts the value and does not send.

```js
function populateSecondTextBox() {
  document.getElementById('cepAddressRouteTransporter').value = document.getElementById('postal_code').value;
}
```

```html
<form action="transporter/route" method="post" role="form">
  <table id="address">
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Zip code</td>
      <td class="wideField">
        <input class="field" id="postal_code" name="postal_code" onkeyup="populateSecondTextBox();">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">directions</i>
    <input placeholder="Ex: 18214-780" id="cepAddressRouteTransporter" name="cepAddressRouteTransporter" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="cepAddressRouteTransporter">CEP:</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it only extracts the value and does not send"

Comment: @sskoko it is only extracting the value entered in input `$('#postal_code').val();` but does not send to input `cepAddressRouteTransporter`

Comment: I've just edited your post to include a code snippet, but your code seems to work just fine.

Comment: @JamesDouglas thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace function in head or in body worked for me.

```
function populateSecondTextBox() {
    document.getElementById('cepAddressRouteTransporter').value = 
    document.getElementById('postal_code').value;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xf04La0h/)

Answer (score 0):

Do the simplest thing

```
onkeyup="document.getElementById('cepAddressRouteTransporter').value = this.value;"
```

Change you onkeyup function call as above.